# Link date dimension with an interval fields in fact table

Tags: ssas

My problem it's very complex, for me anyway! I'll try to explain :
I have the following fact table :

```
ID   Date_From   Date_To     Time_From   Time_To   ID_ACTIV
1    01/02/2018  25/05/2018  08:00:00    10:00:00  41
2    01/06/2018  01/07/2018  10:00:00    13:00:00  41
3    01/02/2018  10/02/2018  10:00:00    11:00:00  42
```

And a normal date dimension I want to link this dimension with fact tab to get this result table in example:

```
Date        hour     ACTIV_COUNT
31/01/2018  10       0
01/02/2018  07       0
01/02/2018  08       1
01/02/2018  09       1
01/02/2018  10       2
01/02/2018  11       1
.
.
01/06/2018  10       1
.
.
```

The only solution that I found it's to create a named query with a field and populate it with all possible dates and times in each interval, then link it with the date and time dimension.
Have you a better solution ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 0

Can you share more data from table because your output is bit confusing. You have start date and hour / end date and hour. And you are looking everyday and hour number of active ID. How do you decide that? If you explain your logic then it will be easy to convert in query.

Comment: what do you mean by all possible dates and times , you should define a date, time interval, please explain more your requirement

Comment: What is your grain? you need just day level info or time/minute/second level info?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy I need both, I have two dimensions Date year/month/day and time hours/minute/second

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55507489/generate-date-range-from-two-date-columns/55507862#55507862 Thanks to @Kaushik Nayak  helped me for the query,  you think that's the best practice to link the interval date with dimension ?