# Generate date range from two date columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

The source table it's following:

```
Id   start_date   end_date    field1
1    01/03/2019   07/03/2019  text1
2    10/04/2019   15/04/2019  text2
```

I would like to get this output:

```
Id date        field1
1  01/03/2019  text1
1  02/03/2019  text1
1  03/03/2019  text1
1  04/03/2019  text1
1  05/03/2019  text1
1  06/03/2019  text1
1  07/04/2019  text1
2  10/04/2019  text2
2  11/04/2019  text2
2  12/04/2019  text2
2  13/04/2019  text2
2  14/04/2019  text2
2  15/04/2019  text2
```

I must use a loop to populate this table ?

Thank you

Comment: Any reason why `08/03, 09/03 ,  10/04`  etc are excluded from the output? Also, show us the query that you have tried so far.

Comment: Why in the result text1 ends at `07/04/2019` while in the table it has end_date=`10/03/2019` ?

Comment: No sorry it's mistake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use a `connect by` query using the [`prior + sys_guid()`](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2526535) trick

```
select id,start_date + level - 1 as "date", field1 from t 
connect by level <= end_date - start_date  + 1
    and prior id = id
and prior sys_guid() is not null;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f398f016d445e9caafeb18bb66dd601c)

Comment: It is better to use PRIOR than Distinct. I removed my answer and upvoted yours

Comment: @Hadi : That's greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @KaushikNayak, but if I want to add one more level for time interval in the same line how can i do that ?

Comment: @KiMaN : You should ask that as a separate question linking this post. Comments are not meant for providing solutions  and this answers your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive CTE, which is SQL standard. For example, the CTE `expanded` in following query works in both Oracle and Postgres (whole query works only in Oracle, will work in Postgres after removing `from dual` and adding `with recursive`):

```
with original as (
  select 1 as id, date '2019-03-01' as start_date, date '2019-03-07' as end_date, 'text1' as field from dual
  union
  select 2 as id, date '2019-04-10' as start_date, date '2019-04-15' as end_date, 'text2' as field from dual
), expanded (id, the_date, end_date, field) as (
  select id, start_date, end_date, field
  from original
  union all
  select original.id, expanded.the_date + 1, original.end_date, original.field
  from expanded
  join original on expanded.id = original.id and expanded.the_date + 1 <= original.end_date
)
select id, the_date, field
from expanded
order by id, the_date
```

See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c0e49c2fff9e24fee8401e8ac9a16ceb

Note: due to [Oracle CTE dating arithmetic bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42512969/653539), the query won't work in Oracle up to 11.2 (you obtain `ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0` error as dates go mistakenly downwards). If you have older Oracle version, it's probably better for you to use connect by, since using CTE requires some workaround of the bug (reverse direction or precomputed sequences), which is tricky as well. For newer Oracle version (or other vendors - if somebody finds this question) I recommend to prefer SQL-standard way.