# how to get sum of filed between two date range where from date and to date is given in table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select sum(task_changepoint) task_changepoint ,Task_id,task_dt_from,task_dt_to
from fb_task 
where (task_dt_from between to_date(:ra_frdt,'dd/mm/yyyy') AND to_date(:ra_todt,'dd/mm/yyyy')) or 
task_dt_to between to_date(:ra_frdt,'dd/mm/yyyy') AND to_date(:ra_todt,'dd/mm/yyyy')
group by Task_id,task_dt_from,task_dt_to
```

Current output is:

| TASK_CHANGEPOINT | TASK_ID | TASK_DT_FROM | TASK_DT_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | ESUB0163 | 26/07/2020 | 01/08/2020 |
| 24 | ESUB0163 | 02/08/2020 | 08/08/2020 |

But I need:

| TASK_CHANGEPOINT | TASK_ID | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | ESUB0163 | 26/07/2020 |
| 24 | ESUB0163 | 27/07/2020 |
| 24 | ESUB0163 | 28/07/2020 |
| 24 | ESUB0163 | 29/07/2020 |
| 24 | ESUB0163 | 23/07/2020 |

Comment: Please, describe the rule to for the output: why it includes 23.07, but doesn't include 01.08? And provide sample data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate date range from two date columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55507489/generate-date-range-from-two-date-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for ? You don't provide sample *input* so I took your initial input as source.

This technique is called **recursive subquery factoring**

```
WITH table_name (task_changepoint, task_id, task_dt_from,task_dt_to) AS
(
SELECT 24,'ESUB0163', DATE '2020-07-26', DATE '2020-08-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 24,'ESUB0163', DATE '2020-08-02', DATE '2020-08-08' FROM DUAL
), row_per_day(task_changepoint, task_id, active_date, task_dt_to) AS
(
SELECT task_changepoint,
       task_id,
       LEAST(task_dt_from, task_dt_to),
       task_dt_to
  FROM table_name
UNION ALL
SELECT task_changepoint,
       task_id,
       LEAST(active_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY, task_dt_to),
       task_dt_to
  FROM row_per_day 
  WHERE active_date < task_dt_to
)
SELECT 
    task_changepoint, 
    task_id, 
    active_date 
  FROM row_per_day 
 ORDER by 
    task_changepoint, 
    active_date;

TASK_CHANGEPOINT TASK_ID  ACTIVE_DATE
---------------- -------- -----------
              24 ESUB0163 26-JUL-2020
              24 ESUB0163 27-JUL-2020
              24 ESUB0163 28-JUL-2020
              24 ESUB0163 29-JUL-2020
              24 ESUB0163 30-JUL-2020
              24 ESUB0163 31-JUL-2020
              24 ESUB0163 01-AUG-2020
              24 ESUB0163 02-AUG-2020
              24 ESUB0163 03-AUG-2020
              24 ESUB0163 04-AUG-2020
              24 ESUB0163 05-AUG-2020
              24 ESUB0163 06-AUG-2020
              24 ESUB0163 07-AUG-2020
              24 ESUB0163 08-AUG-2020
```